# Generate Arrays and get only the numbers above Average

Tags: c#, arrays

So, I'm trying to make an array that generates 20 random integers below 100, and I want to write only the numers I got from that array that are above the average, here is the code I'm using, can't proceed without knowing what I have to do now...

PS: I know my foreach is wrong, can I get some help with that too?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int average, aboveAverage;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int[] vetor;

        array = new int[20];

        array[0] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[1] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[2] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[3] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[4] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[5] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[6] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[7] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[8] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[9] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[10] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[11] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[12] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[13] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[14] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[15] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[16] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[17] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[18] = random.Next(0, 100);
        array[19] = random.Next(0, 100);

        foreach (int elements in array)
        {
            average = elements / 20;
            aboveAverage = ???
            Console.WriteLine("{0} integers are above average.", aboveAverage);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
       }
     }
   }
}
```

So, here's what I've made, last I checked it was working fine ^_^ thx for the help everyone, appreciate it so much, wish I could choose everyone's answer!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int sumNumbers, average;
   int aboveAverage = 0;

   int[] array = new int[20];

   Random random = new Random();
   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   {
       array[i] = random.Next(0, 100);
   }
       sumNumbers = array.Sum();
       average = sumNumbers / 20;
       foreach (var elements in array)
       {
           if (elements > average)
           {
               aboveAverage++;
           }
       }
       Console.WriteLine("{0} numbers are above average.", aboveAverage);
       Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sum all items in array and then divide by 20, just dividing by 20  wont give you average

Comment: write for loop to initialize array elements instead of 20 lines

Comment: I think you should clarify if this is homework or an excercise, or if it's something you actually need to do and the question is just an example; the best solution for this is to use LINQ but maybe you can't/should't use it so answers consider that.

Comment: Yes it is an exercise from a book in my country, I can't use LINQ, here is what the exercise asks:

1. Make a program that:

a) Generate 20 integers in an array below 100.

b) Calculate the average os these numbers.

c) Determine and write how many numbers are above average.

Comment: @Hykky - your solution looks good. A small note - Array.Sum uses Linq, so if you want a solution without Linq, you need to implement sum yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split it into two steps. First calculate the average. Using linq it will look like this::

```
var average = array.Average();
```

And then retrieve only those above average:

```
var aboveAverage = string.Join(", " array.Where(item => item > average));
Console.WriteLine($"{aboveAverage} integers are above average.");
```

- The `$""` syntax is C# 6.0 String Interpolation

Also you can generate all the random numbers in a nicer way using `Enumerable.Repeat` and `.Select`:

```
var array = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 20).Select(item => random.Next(0, 100)).ToArray();
```

---

Without linq then first iterate the collection once to sum all items so you can calculate average and then once again to find all those greater than the average:

```
int sum = 0;
foreach(var item in array)
{ 
    sum += item;
}
var average = sum * 1.0 / array.Length;

List<int> aboveAverageItems = new List<int>();
foreach(var item in array)
{
    if(item > average)
    {
        //If you need to know how many items and not which then use a counter and increase
        aboveAverageItems.Add(item);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(", " aboveAverageItems)} integers are above average.");
```

Comment: I think you should clarify that this is using LINQ; the question seems like either homework or an excercise from a book/tutorial, and OP might not be able to use nothing more than basic flow structures.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - doing it the way you suggest will generate a collection of 20 items with the same value

Comment: @Hykky - do you want to know how many are above average or which are above average?

Comment: You could write your `Repeat` differently to not have to locally declare `random` : `var array = Enumerable.Repeat(new Random (), 20).Select(rnd => rnd.Next (100)).ToArray ();` The behaviour of `Repeat` garantees that "each" `rnd` will refer to the same `Random` instance.

Comment: I think I got it to work, I'll update the post and put the code I made again in the end, can you check if it's right for me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments above saying that this might come from a homework assignment. I'd like to point out a few flaws in your code and point you towards the right direction in hopes that you will solve this on your own:

1. You do not need the outer for loop. I think you might have gotten confused due to the fact that you need to create numbers smaller than 100, and maybe this is part of some older code.
2. You do not need the 'vetor' variable.
3. When you are creating your array, you can keep the current sum of elements in your array. Create a variable called totalSum, and every time you create an element, add it's value to totalSum. Once you have initialized the array, you will also have the sum of all elements in the array.
4. Your foreach is a bit misleading. Consider writing it as foreach (int **element** in array). Every iteration you only have a single element. That will make it clear that a line such as element \ 20 does not make a lot of sense.
5. Before your foreach, calculate the average by totalSum \ number of elements. In your foreach, check if an element is greater than the sum. If so, add it to list. Finally, return all the elements which are in your list.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

without linq, do it like this:

```
int sum = 0;
foreach (int elements in array)
{

    sum = sum + elements;
}

var avg = sum / 20;

var aboveAvgCount = 0;
foreach (int elements in array)
{

    if (elements > avg)
    {
        aboveAvgCount = aboveAvgCount + 1;
    }
}
```